# How to cancel a flight with Spirit Airlines

Tags: air-travel

I am an inexperienced traveler who booked a flight to Seattle for a family wedding. Situations have come up for me to cancel or change my flight.

The flight is through Spirit and I wanted to be clear about the wording of their policy.

> 2.4.1 - No refunds will be given for cancellations and any remaining amount will be placed as a credit and may be applied to future travel. Such credits are good for travel booked within 60 days of issuance for travel on any flight dates available in the system and shall not have any cash value. [Source](https://www.spirit.com/content/documents/en-us/General_Terms_and_Conditions.pdf)

Does this mean that:

1. I have to take a flight within 60 days of the initial booking
2. I book my flight within 60 days of the initial book and can go on said flight on day 61+?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Such credits are good for travel **booked within 60 days of issuance**...

means you can use the credits as long as you book within 60 days of the credits being issued.

> ...for travel on **any flight dates available in the system**

means the flights you book can be any that are in the entire booking system at the time you book.

Comment: Sadly, though, this does not answer the question. I understand booking (buying) has to be done within 60 days. But does the flight also have to be within those 60 or can I book (buy) a ticket thats scheduled for a year later?

Comment: As I said you can book tickets to travel on **any flight dates available in the system**. That means the whole booking system It will include flights more than 60 days in advance.